# Spring OauthServer how to authenticate 2 clients at once

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

My understanding of an Oauth2.0 Server is that it grants clients access to resources when the resource owner has granted permission to a client.  So say I have a user Bob and he's given permission to two clients (client1, client2) to access his stuff.  As part of that Bob logs in 2x.  Once like so:

```
http://10.234.233.23:9081/oauth/authorize?client_id=client1&response_type=code&scope=all
```

and he gets an auth-code -> `FIbSqy`
and again like so for the second client

```
http://10.234.233.23:9081/oauth/authorize?client_id=client2&response_type=code&scope=all
```

and again he gets a second auth-code -> `h4ckJQ`

He hands those auth-codes off to app1 and app2 respectively.  Then those clients log into the oauth server and exchange those auth-codes for tokens.  Then ever after the tokens are used to make calls and get resources.

My question is how the heck do you authenticate two clients at once on the auth server when the auth server appears to cache the first person's credentials and then never lets anyone else login.

Because for me the first client to exchange an auth code for a token...gets tokens and every other sorry client afterwards gets the following error:
[image]

I know you can register clients...and I have them all registered with the outh server...but is there also a "login" url that I'm missing that lets them all login at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth supports `state`. This is recommended to prevent cross-site request forgery. This state can be used to support multiple logins simultaneously.

`http://10.234.233.23:9081/oauth/authorize?client_id=client1&response_type=code&scope=all&state=some-big-random-number-string`

Comment: I tried state yesterday without success.  It does of course then require you to match the state(nonce) or it rejects you but it still thinks it's the first authorized client.

Comment: I parsed through the spring code a bit and found that it's the SpringSecurityContext that stores the authenticated client..but I can't figure out how to purge it.  Thanks for your suggestion though.